# How do i clear the panel after drawing Graphics objects on it?

Tags: java

I have a panel in which i draw a number of graphics objects on using the paintComponent method and the Graphics methods to draw.

I need to create a button, that you click and then it clears the panel.
example :

```
JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
 if(e.getSource()==clear){
   //button code here
   }
}
```

What i need is the code that goes inside that IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

The paintComponent method will get called everytime a repaint is called and this method draw what you write in it everytime.If you want to clear a screen of object then you must remove the object(a button for example) from the panel/frame on the button click function.

It is not a good practice to write logic code in the paintComponent method with boolean etc.

Comment: Who told you that advice? simple if statements??? You are only right in long computations where one should use `SwingWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
private boolean clear = false;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(clear)
        return;
    }
    // all your graphics here

}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   if(e.getSource()==clearButton){
       clear = true;
       repaint();
   }
}
```

Don't forget to change back the `clear` flag, at some point of the program, when you want to allow drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways of doing custom painting:

1. paint objects contained in a List, in which case you would clear the List
2. paint onto a BufferedImage, in which case you would clear the BufferedImage

The examples code shows how "Clear" would be done in both cases.